# XSD for a tree of string key-value pairs

Tags: xml, xsd

I'd like to build a XSD for a tree of string key-value pairs.
Something to fit this:

```
<entry>
  <key>root</key>
    <entry key="name">john</entry>
    <entry key="address">
      <entry key="street">Rou de Flon 1</entry>
      <entry key="city">Lausanne</entry>
   </entry>
</entry>
```

I didn't manage to get this (I want to use xsd:string, and not xsd:anyType)

This alternative pattern:

```
<entry>
  <key>root</key>
    <entry>
      <key>name</key>
      <value>john</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key>address</key>
      <entry>
        <key>street</key>
        <value>Rou de Flon 1</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <key>city</key>
        <value>Lausanne</value>
      </entry>
   </entry>
</entry>
```

can be done with:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="Entry">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="rbo:Entry"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

but I would prefer to use the first pattern, because it is more compact.

I tried this other XSD:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="ValueEntry">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="key" use="required" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="ListEntry">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="rbo:ListOrValueEntry"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="key" use="required" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="ListOrValueEntry">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="value" type="rbo:ValueEntry"/>
        <xsd:element name="entry" type="rbo:ListEntry"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

but it produces more ugly XML:

```
<listEntry>
  <entry>
    <value key="name">john</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <entry key="address">
      <entry>
        <value key="street">Rou de Flon 1</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <value key="city">Lausanne</value>
      </entry>
    </entry>
  </entry>
</listEntry>
```

So, is there a way to create a XSD for this pattern, without using xsd:anyType?

```
<entry>
  <key>root</key>
    <entry key="name">john</entry>
    <entry key="address">
      <entry key="street">Rou de Flon 1</entry>
      <entry key="city">Lausanne</entry>
   </entry>
</entry>
```

ps: please, don't discuss whether you like this pattern or not; that's a nice discussion, but it is not the objective of this post.
the objective of this post is to find out how to, if at all possible, write XSD for this XML, without using xsd:anyType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use different tag names for string and non-string elements. Most close structure would be

```
<entry key="root">
    <value key="name">john</value>
    <entry key="address">
      <value key="street">Rou de Flon 1</value>
      <value key="city">Lausanne</value>
   </entry>
</entry>
```

Schema for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="entry" type="entryType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="entryType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element type="valueType" name="value"/>
            <xs:element type="entryType" name="entry"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="valueType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

However, it's the XML. More readable will be:

```
<root>
  <name>john</name>
  <address>
    <street>Rou de Flon 1</street>
    <city>Lausanne</city>
  </address>
</root>
```

Comment: I tried the option of using different tag names for string and non-string elements, but I didn't managet to build a XSD for it. that was what i was trying with the big XSD that I included in the post, but it produces the "ugly XML" that i mention in the post.
Do you know how to build a XSD that is valid with your example?

Comment: about the "more readable will be...", I agree, that's the purpose of XML and XSD. however, for specific reasons of a project, I need a tree of string value-key pairs that are not predefined in advance.

Comment: I've added an XSD for the XML. Also, if you need a tree of the pairs, which is not predefined - it's exactly what the XML is. What's a point to "define not predefined" with XSD?

Answer (score 0):

You have to used mixed content on your definition for `Entry`. Also you need the minOccurs="0".

```
<xsd:complexType name="Entry" mixed="true">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Entry"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

This allows you to have the exact structure you want.

Comment: It will allow things like `<entry key="root">aaaa<entry key="name">bbb</entry>ccc</entry>`. Not exactly what he wants, as I understand.

Comment: I have changed the code sample so now it will support the extra "key" element at the top. So now it does allow him to have the exact structure he wants.

Comment: I mean that `mixed=true` allows mix tags and text. But he wants (IIUC) an element which has only tags or only text, and not together.

Comment: OK I see what you are saying but actually the OP did not specifically state this was a requirement. I think you inferred that from the code samples. It may well be perfectly acceptable to have mixed content allowed but just not together at the same node.

Comment: this does not allow <entry key="name">john</entry>,because there is the "key" tag that you need to enter (that should be named "value" in any case). this allows <entry key="name"><key>john</key></entry>, which is not desired.

Comment: According to your original post you wanted a schema which would validate your desired XML instance. Nowhere in your original post do you require there to be a "value" node. Additionally the "key" node in my sample is not required, although it does, as you say, allow certain configurations which you now say are invalid. The schema fragment I posted will validate the instance you specified in your original post. If this was not your requirement then why did you post the question? I am unsure why you awarded the answer to the other poster, who also was unable to address your requirement.